# How to assign id from php array to input

Tags: php

I want this to return two hidden inputs with with productcount1 & productcount2.

The below is returning productcount1,2 for one input only.

The array is as follows: 1,2,4,9

```
$allquizproducts = 1,2,4,9
$array = explode(', ', $allquizproducts);
$i=0;
foreach($array as $value) 
{ ?>
<input id="productcount<?php echo $value[$i] ?>" type="hidden" value="0">
<?php $i++; }
```

Comment: `$value[$i]` ? `$value` is a string, not an array. You probably want this, `echo $value . ($i + 1);`, assuming `$i` starts with `0`.

Comment: No I don't. I need to print out each item in my array after product count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in [**my comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790307/how-to-assign-id-from-php-array-to-input/41790395#comment70769427_41790307),

`$value` is a string, not an array, so `$value[$i]` is wrong.

From [**OP's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790307/how-to-assign-id-from-php-array-to-input#comment70769520_41790307),

> I need to print out each item in my array after product count

Change your `explode(...);` statement and subsequent `foreach` loop like this:

```
$array = array_unique(explode(',', $allquizproducts));
foreach($array as $value) { 
    ?>
    <input id="productcount<?php echo $value; ?>" type="hidden" value="productcount<?php echo $value; ?>">
    <?php 
}
```

Please note that there's no point using variable `$i` in your code.

Comment: this would return productcount1, productcount2, productcount2, productcount4 but not the values in my array

Comment: @InnovBee So you want to update the `value` attribute as well, right?

Comment: yep I need productcount1, productcount2, productcount4, productcount9 as per my array

Comment: For some reason it is only creating one hidden input with productcount1,2,4,9 as the id

Comment: @InnovBee I've updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing string like array. You have to change your line like below:

```
<input id="productcount<?php echo $value; ?>" type="hidden" value="0">
```

Comment: yes the string is 1,2,4,9 and I need to show each of these values after productcount

Comment: it is still giving me one input box with the id of productcount1,2

Comment: you want seperate iput hidden boxes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get diiferent hidden boxes for each product, you need to use a for loop as below. Strongly recommend to add name attribute also in order to access in post

```
<?php
$allquizproducts = '1,2,4,9';
$array = explode(',', $allquizproducts);

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{ ?>
<input name="values<?php echo $array[$i]; ?>"  id="values<?php echo $array[$i]; ?>"  type="hidden" value="0">   
<?php }  ?>
```